# Problema enviar email codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

alguém poderia por gentileza me ajudar, é um problema que eu ja procurei aqui e não encontrei o erro ainda.

O problema é o seguinte, estou tentando enviar email no servidor que estou utilizando atualmente onde ele é ssl e smtp, mas ele fica dando sempre o mesmo erro e eu não estou conseguindo encontrar o problema faz mais de uma semana, o codigo no meu controller está o seguinte:

```
        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';  
        $config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'smtp.XXXX';
        $config['smtp_user'] = 'XXX';
        $config['smtp_pass'] = 'XXXX';
        $config['smtp_port'] = 587;
        $config['smtp_keepalive'] = TRUE;
        $config['smtp_crypto'] = 'ssl';
        $this->email->initialize($config);
        $this->email->from("meuemail@hotmail.com",'teste');
        $this->email->to("emailtesteaserenviado@hotmail.com");
        $this->email->subject("teste");
        $this->email->message("teste");
        $this->email->send();
        echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

e ele está dando os seguintes erros:

> Message: fsockopen(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol
>
> Message: fsockopen(): Failed to enable crypto
>
> Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.XXX:587 (Unknown error)

eu não estou conseguindo arrumar em lugar nenhum, ja coloquei o seguinte codigo no php.ini:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

entretanto não funcionou, utilizando o phpinfo e percebi que na parte de `Registered Stream Socket Transports` tem `ssl,sslv3,tsl` entre outros mas não tem o sslv2 mas eu não sei se isso influencia, se esse dever ser o erro ou qual seria o problema.

já tentei utilizar o phpmailer mas não consegui utilizar ele corretamente, ele fala que a classe está incorreta ou algo do gênero, então não sei muito bem o que fazer.

O phpmailer sem a utilização do codeiginter está funcionando com as configurações, entretanto no codeiginter não consigo enviar utilizando as mesmas configurações, alguém poderia por gentileza me ajudar, está um pouco difícil de encontrar algo que auxilie nessa parte.

muito obrigado a todos pelo auxilio.

Comment: Tentou habilitar a extensão no php.ini? ou no cpanel selector?

Comment: Sim, eu habilitei a extensão, elá está habilitada no php.ini

Answer (score -1):

É possível que você esteja realizando autenticação no SMTP com email X e tentando enviar com FROM de email Y.

Exemplo (que não funciona):

```
application/config/email.php
...
$config['smtp_user'] = 'outroemail@hotmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'ZzZZzZz';
...
$this->email->from("meuemail@hotmail.com",'teste');
```

Exemplo (que funciona):

```
application/config/email.php
...
$config['smtp_user'] = 'meuemail@hotmail.com';
$config['smtp_pass'] = 'ZzZZzZz';
...
$this->email->from("meuemail@hotmail.com",'teste');
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).